# Making DHIS2 work with postgresql

Tags: dhis2

We are facing issues with deployment of DHIS2 with PostgreSQL on AWS. We need help. This is our setup:
1. AWS Beanstalk Tomcat container running DHIS2 (last stable release)
2. AWS RDS instance of Postgresql

My question is:
- How do I make DHIS2 use PostgreSQL. Documentation talks about configuring the setup using hibernate.properties ... but where is that file?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the hibernate.properties config file yourself. Note that after version 2.22 the file is called *dhis.conf*. You can place the configuration in whichever location you prefer. You must define an environment variable called *DHIS2_HOME* which points to the directory in which you placed the dhis.conf / hibernate.properties file.

You can define environment variables in the Beanstalk Web interface from Configuration > Software configuration.

DHIS 2 installation documentation is found [here](http://dhis2.github.io/dhis2-docs/master/en/implementer/html/ch08.html).

AWS Beanstalk environment variables documentation is found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/deploy/envvar.html).